# How to pass i18n or t function to dependency using next-i18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

I have two repositories. One with `nextjs` application and second one with components that are being dynamically loaded into the first repo.

Since some of the components in second repo contain translations, I need to pass down a `t` function or an `i18n` instance (translation files and `next-i18next` initialisation are in the first repo).

I tried to pass it using context provider, but that didn't work:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'translator' of undefined

Is there any recommended way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since at runtime your components sharing the same React "tree", there are many ways to achieve your requirement:

1. passing the `t` method itself - creates a couple between your component and it's environment.

```js
<InnerComponent t={t} />
```

2. passing an already translated text to the component - your component may remain "general" purpose. but sometimes large components may require many texts, will cause a large amount of props.

```js
<InnerComponent title={t('MY_TITLE')} />
```

There are cons & pros for each method, decide what is suites your requirements.